# Typecheck generated code that access dynamically loaded code in Haskell

Tags: haskell, code-generation

I need a fast way (1000's of typechecks per second) to typecheck generated Haskell source code.

We tried [hint](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hint) which was fast enough except it cannot access dynamically loaded code unless the source code is available which we would not have in some cases. Maybe there is some way to register dynamically loaded code as a package or something since hint can access registered packages it seems?

We tried using the ghc api, but it appears to require the files be on disk and all the file IO required makes it too slow.

We can use [haskell-src-exts](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskell-src-exts) to generate the code, but we need to typecheck it.

Comment: Perhaps you could go with the GHC api solution, and put everything necessary in a ram disk?

Comment: This is an application to be distributed to end users, so I don't have control over their system configuration.

Comment: would it be possible to feed the GHC api file-descriptors instead of file location?  Then it wouldn't be hard to avoid talking to disk for the content (which I assume you have in ram)

Comment: If IO from disk is a problem for the GHC API, what about putting the files on a ramdisk? That would help I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thousands of type checks per second doesn't seem feasible sequentially -- you're doing these concurrently, with some hope for parallelism I hope?

And I assume you are supporting the full GHC type system? So a stripped down type checker (e.g. [THIH](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/thih) won't suffice).

- Use ghc-api, with bytecode and no optimizations
- Cache everything in memory
- Submit modifications to GHC to ensure it can take FDs from memory buffers, if necessary

Comment: Actually, Hint was giving us at least a thousand per second, I think. But it wouldn't work with object code so had to find a different solution. However, another solution is get around the "sequentially" you mention: put all the typechecks needed in a single file and type check just once. It can be a little tricky to translate error messages, but it seemed to work ok for simple things we were trying.

Comment: "a thousand per second" -- but it depends on the program -- and there are some programs that cause the type checker not to terminate...